# How to break out of a asyncio coroutine without using the `return` statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I'm having a bit of trouble deciding how to break out of this coroutine if the `except` statement catches. Normally, I would just use:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        foo_var = next(a_volitile_generator(x))
    except Exception:
        print('it broked')
        return
    yield foo_var
```

However! I'm going to spawn a gazillion of these generator funcs, make them coroutines, and finally `Future`ize them & load them into an event-loop. Here's the issue:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100)

async def f(x, result_queue, *, loop=loop):
    while _some_condition() is True:
        try:
            foo_var = await a_volitile_async_generator(x)
        except Exception:
            print('it broked')
            # HELP BELOW
            raise StopAsyncIteration # <--ONLY OPTION????????
        await result_queue.put(foo_var)
```

returning anything **into the event-loop** is a no-no in `asyncio` because you'll break everything...even if that value is `None`.

Aside from that, let's also say I'd like to avoid raising `StopAsyncIteration`...I'm trying to figure out if that's the only way to do this or if I have other options:

Comment: What about `break` or `continue`?

Comment: ...oh woah yeah `break` cuz I'm in a `while` loop...(>_<) thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196720/how-to-break-out-of-a-asyncio-coroutine-without-using-the-return-statement/48196983#comment83374777_48196720) by @dirn in the comments, you can replace your `raise StopAsyncIteration` line with a simple `break`:

```
async def f(x, result_queue, *, loop=loop):
    while _some_condition() is True:
        try:
            foo_var = await a_volitile_async_generator(x)
        except Exception:
            print('it broked')
            break
        await result_queue.put(foo_var)
```

Comment: Added mainly because OP's self-answer got deleted, and comments are fragile.

Answer (score 0):

JFYI, I guess, you're doing something wrong.

```
yield from a_volitile_async_generator(x)
```

If `a_volitile_async_generator` is a real async generator, it won't work: you [can't use](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-yield-from) `yield from` with it.

Comment: My bad. That should be an `await`.