# Async looped function stop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, discord.py

I'm trying to make an async looped(with the infinity 'while' inside) function stopped by another function. Is it possible at all? Already tried exceptions.

Looks like this:

```
    async def loopedfunc():
        a = True
        while True:
            do something
        await etc..
```

After i've stated the function i need to stop it. As like you got a special timer which you can turn on and turn off whenever you need.

Comment: would `loopedfunc.break = False` outside of the func and `while not loopedfunc.break:` inside it work? would still only break from the while on passing the check though

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196720/how-to-break-out-of-a-asyncio-coroutine-without-using-the-return-statement

Answer (score 0):

Finally, when I was unable to stop an infinite async function with another function, I decided to go the other way. The Discord Library has an async loop function. unfortunately there is no printout in it, because this function does not pass arguments.
I had to create another async function and make its argument global. Then in Async Loop Function I was able to print what I needed to the screen using a argument of another function.